# Ruby banking system program

Tags: beginner, object-oriented, ruby

As a beginner I'd like to get any kind of feedback. The more the better. Any optimization and style mistakes?

```
class Account
      attr_reader :name, :balance

      def initialize(name, balance=100)
        @name = name
        @balance = balance
      end   

      private

      def pin
      @pin = 789 
      end  

      def pin_check
        puts "Welcome to the banking system, #{@name}!\n" + "To access your account, input PIN please"
        @input_pin = gets.chomp.to_i
      end      

     def pin_error 
        return "Access denied: incorrect PIN."
     end

    public

      def access
        if pin_check == pin
          puts "Input d: to deposit money, s: to show balance or w: to withdraw money"
          action = gets.chomp.downcase
            case action
            when "d"
            deposit
            when "s"
            display_balance
            when "w"
           withdraw
            else
        puts "Try again"
          end
        else puts pin_error
        end    
      end

      def amount
        puts "Input the amount"
        @money = gets.to_i
      end

      def over_error
        print "You don't own that kind of money, dude! Your balance: $#{@balance}"
      end

      def deposit
       @balance += amount
        puts "Deposited: $#{@money}. Updated balance: $#{@balance}."
      end

      def display_balance
        puts "Balance: $#{@balance}."   
      end

      def withdraw
        if  amount <= @balance
          @balance -= @money
           puts "Withdrew: $#{@money}. Updated balance: $#{@balance}."  
        else
            puts over_error
        end
      end
    end  

    checking_account = Account.new("James Bond", 520_000)
    checking_account.access
```

Comment: this is quite lovely. i really don't have much to add to it. i guess you only want the access method to be publicly available. the rest you would probably leave as private methods - because they might change. but this is pretty sweet IMO and i can't comment unless there are further changes to the requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice implementation. The comments I have are mostly about overall structure.

I do have one comment on some low-level stuff: Use a string for the PIN instead of an int. When it's an integer, you can't have leading zeros, so if James Bond's PIN is `007`, you could enter `7`, `07`, or `0000000007`, and all would be equally valid. That's no good (and James Bond - already the world's worst "secret" agent is a fool for having that PIN anyway).

I'd also suggest making the PIN a constructor argument - otherwise everyone in your bank will have the same hard-coded PIN. Not exactly secure.

As for structure: Your `Account` class isn't only an account - it's a complete ATM, too. User interface (the command line in this case), is mixed in with the business logic of managing the balance.

I'd suggest separating those concerns. One would be the `Account` model/class that holds the information, and performs actions on said information, and the other would encapsulate the user interface.

Right now, if you decide that you want to do web banking too - not just command line banking - you'd run into trouble. You'd have to make a brand new `Account` class to handle it. But that wouldn't make sense, since mr Bond only has (or should only have) one account - not different ones depending on how he's accessing them.

I'd do something like this:

```
class Account
  attr_reader :name, :balance

  def initialize(name, pin, balance)
    @name = name
    @pin = pin # TODO: Check that it's a valid PIN and not just blank or something
    @balance = balance
  end

  def valid_pin?(pin)
    @pin == pin
  end

  def withdraw(amount)
    # subtract amount from balance or raise error if balance
    # isn't large enough (or amount is negative)
  end

  def deposit(amount)
    # add amount to balance or raise error if amount is negative
  end
end

class Atm
  def initialize(account)
    @account = account
  end

  # ...
end
```

The `Atm` class handles all the user interaction much like now, but delegates the actual withdrawal/depositing and PIN checking to the account. How you structure it from here is up to you, but the basic point is that the account is "just" an account.

Comment: 1. Nice one, though it doesn't work right after i've replaced int with string for pin input. I'll continue trying.

Comment: 2. I'll definitely make some structural changes, got your point.

Comment: hello, can you give me the hint please, how to make these two classes work together without inheritance or using "Account" as a module? In your example you are passing the amount as an argument for two different methods. It is supposed to get the actual amount from the user input in the Atm class? I didn't ask right away because I thought I could figure this out myself, with the help of mighty google. Found some examples of simple ATM programs in Ruby and Python (since it very similar and more popular now).

Comment: Got some interesting new ideas, but nothing to help me figure out how to do this in the way that you mean. And can you tell me more about problems I'd run into if i'll use my current structure for web app? What kind of problems? Sorry but as a beginner I don't see it clearly :).

Comment: @Flynn84 I'll try to update my answer with more details. Bit busy at the moment, I'm afraid, but will try to get to it

Comment: @Flynn84 Apologies, but it seems I won't have time to add much to my answer for the next couple days. But to quickly answer you question about using it for a web app: Your current code expect input from a terminal (asking for the the PIN, and you typing it in, etc.), but if you're running things on a server, people would be using it through a browser: There's no terminal. Hence why I said to separate user interface (terminal in this case, website in another) from core functionality (the account)

Comment: If you'll have something more to add some day I'm still really curious to read it :). Don't mean to rush you, just to show you that I'm interested. Maybe I can figure out exactly what you mean myself but I have a feeling that I'm probably overcomplicating things in my head.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things that I would do differently and/or change:

- I usually find it easier to put all the public methods at the top and the private methods at the bottom instead of mixing them. This is also what I see most people do.
- Be consistent. In `pin_error` you return an error message, in `over_error` you `print` the message (elsewhere you use `puts`). I would make both methods just `puts` the error message.
- I would not assign an instance variable in `amount` just return the value and then change `withdraw` to use a local variable. I would also call it `get_amount` or something since it does more than just return an amount.

  ```
  def withdraw
    amt = get_amount
    if  amt <= @balance
      @balance -= amt
      puts "Withdrew: $#{amt}. Updated balance: $#{@balance}."  
    else
      over_error
    end
  end
  ```
- The `pin` method is odd in that it returns the bin but also sets an instance variable unnecessarily. I would pass the pin into the constructor.
- I would make `pin_check` actually check if the pin is correct and return true or false. I would also give it an active name, with a bang, like `check_pin!`

Comment: 1. I've read on stackowerflow probably week or two ago that it's better to have all private methods at the top, so I have them there. Except initialize, that always should be at the top? I hope I understand it properly that there is need to put "private" before every method you want to be private? They all private before I put the "public" word? I've checked - it worked in this program.

Comment: 2. Yeah, thanks. That is obvious, I've never even paid attention to these methods since they worked properly from the very beginning.

Comment: 3. Other suggestions are useful too, thanks.

Comment: Nice answer +1. Took the liberty of editing just to format the code block (it was being rendered as regular text)

Comment: wrt To private positioning, all the projects I have worked on have them at the bottom and that is my preference but it doesn't really matter as long as you are consistent within a project.

Answer (score 1):

There are few guidelines which I would follow while coding in Ruby:

- Indentation in Ruby is 2 spaces.
- In any program or project, improve understanding of the project by using proper documentation. Like Java has Javadoc for documentation, Ruby has Tomdoc, which helps in providing documentation to project.
- Rubocop is a gem in Ruby, which can be installed on the local system, and from project location, when we run rubocop gives warning on style.
- `attr_reader` method is used to read variables; `attr_writer` method is used to write variables. To both read and write, we use `attr_accessor`. In your case `balance` is read and written, so we can use `attr_accessor`.
- Usually in Banking sector, the menu option repeats after transaction. Even in your case that can be achieved, by providing `wcase` statement in the `while` loop and the menu can have another option: `exit :e`.
- Pin is unique for each user; we can prompt user to enter pin rather than hardcoding it.
- We can use proper exception Handling. Instead of just printing the error message we can raise the error and rescue the error message from calling application.